# ASP DBContext Best Practies

Tags: c#, entity-framework

After googling a while I would like to know which is best pratices for DBContext (EntityFramework or Linq-to-Sql).

In practise I would lie to know which one of the following "patterns" has less cons:

1) Get Code From [Here](http://www.carlosble.com/2012/02/linq-to-sql-horrors/)

```cs
public class ContextFactory
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static DBDataContext context;
     //Get connectionString from web.config
    private static readonly string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString1"].ConnectionString; 

    public static DBDataContext Context()
    {
        if (context == null)
            context = new DBDataContext(connString);
        return context;
    }

    public static void FlushContext()
    {
        context = new DBSkillDataContext(connString);
    } 
}
```

In this way i use FlushContext each time Controller is initialized.

2) In this way (get code from [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/575189/YaBlogEngineMVC-A-Tiny-Blog-Engine-written-in-ASP))

```cs
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
   {
    DBContext context= null;
    IUserRepository userRepo = null;
    IAccountRepository accountRepo = null; 

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        context= new DBContext();
        userRepo= new UserRepository(context);
        accountRepo= new accountRepo(context); 
    }

    public IUserRepository userRepo 
    {
        get
        {
            return userRepo;
        }
    }

    public IAccountRepository accountRepo 
    {
        get
        {
            return accountRepo;
        }
    } 

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // If this function is being called the user wants to release the
        // resources. lets call the Dispose which will do this for us.
        Dispose(true);

        // Now since we have done the cleanup already there is nothing left
        // for the Finalizer to do. So lets tell the GC not to call it later.
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing == true)
        {
            //someone want the deterministic release of all resources
            //Let us release all the managed resources
            context= null;
        }
    }

    ~UnitOfWork()
    {
        // The object went out of scope and finalized is called
        // Lets call dispose in to release unmanaged resources 
        // the managed resources will anyways be released when GC 
        // runs the next time.
        Dispose(false);
    }
} 

public abstract class AController : Controller
{
    private IUnitOfWork IUnitOfWork;

    protected IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork_
    {
        get { return IUnitOfWork; }
    }

    public AController(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        this.IUnitOfWork = uow; 
    }
}

public class UserController : AController
{
    // use our DbContext unit of work in case the page runs
    public UserController()
        : this(new UnitOfWork())
    {

    }

    // We will directly call this from the test projects
    public UserController(UnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        : base (unitOfWork)
    {

    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<User> users= UnitOfWork_.usersRepo.GetUsers();

        return View(users);
    }
```

}

So what I'm asking is, which one of the above is best practice to use?

Answer (score 0):

Don't make DbContext static. DbContext is not thread safe and making it static makes it easy to use from multiple threads - especially in we scenarios which may lead to hard to debug/resolve bugs and maybe even data corruption. In additon keeping context alive for extended periods of time is not a good idea - it will track more and more entities and therefore will gradually get slower and slower. It will also prevent GC from collecting objects that are being tracked but are not used. 
The other example is much better. DbContext itself is kind of UnitOfWork. I am not sure if I would start with the Reposiory pattern here. I would rather use the DbContext directly and move to using patterns when they emerge from my code and only if there is a benefit from using the pattern (note that patterns require more code that needs to be understood and maintained).